# jQuery BlockUI Element blocking not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<table>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$(function(){
    $(".cruisedropd").hide();
    $('.save').click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest("tbody.iteration");
        $(parent).block({ message: null }); 

        parent.toggleClass('is_loading',  parent.hasClass('is_loading') );
        parent.find(".cruisedropd").toggle();
        parent.find('.loading').html("work");

    });


});
```

Demo is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/8Mcr6/228/

In firefox, When I click button more, element that is blocked is the element that is selected. It is true
But in chrome, When I click button more, all element blocked. It is false.

How to keep in chrome work?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not working in the `chrome` as the `block` plugin which you have used is generating `DIV` element which should be placed after `element` on which you have applied it, i.e. `tbody.iteration`. Since `table` can't have `DIV` as direct element i.e. [Reference: Permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), chrome is fix it for you thus its not working.

You should change the HTML structure. as provided below.

```
<table>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody class="iteration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="save">More</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cruisedropd">
          <div class="loading"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can use only one table?

Comment: No, I would recommend you to change the `structure` to div based i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/LzLj0dre/